# Amazon SNS (Terraform) Invalid parameter: Policy statement action out of service scope

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, amazon-sns, snowpipe

I want to create an IAM policy document and attached two values taken from snowflake error integration as Trusted Relationship in the policy. Following this tutorial [Step 5](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/data-load-snowpipe-errors-sns.html#step-5-granting-snowflake-access-to-the-sns-topic).

The idea is that to add `SF_AWS_IAM_USER_ARN` and `SF_AWS_EXTERNAL_ID` created from
[SNOWFLAKE NOTIFICATION INTEGRATION](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/sql/create-notification-integration.html) to the policy.

The integration is succesfully created.

This is part of my code:

```
resource "random_id" "random" {
  byte_length = 8
}
resource "aws_sns_topic" "my_sns_topic" {
  name = "${var.bucket_name}-errors-${random_id.random.id}"
}

data "aws_iam_policy_document" "snowflake_notification_error" {
  version = "2008-10-17"
  statement {
    sid = "__default_statement_ID"
    actions = [
      "SNS:GetTopicAttributes",
      "SNS:SetTopicAttributes",
      "SNS:AddPermission",
      "SNS:RemovePermission",
      "SNS:DeleteTopic",
      "SNS:Subscribe",
      "SNS:ListSubscriptionsByTopic",
      "SNS:Publish",
      "SNS:Receive",
    ]
    principals {
      type        = "AWS"
      identifiers = ["*"]
    }
    resources = [aws_sns_topic.my_sns_topic.arn]
    condition {
      test     = "StringEquals"
      variable = "AWS:SourceOwner"
      values   = [data.aws_caller_identity.current.account_id]
    }
  }
  statement {
    sid = "allow_s3_notification"
    principals {
      type        = "Service"
      identifiers = ["s3.amazonaws.com"]
    }

    actions   = ["SNS:Publish"]
    resources = [aws_sns_topic.my_sns_topic.arn]
    condition {
      test     = "ArnLike"
      variable = "aws:SourceArn"
      values   = [data.aws_s3_bucket.bucket.arn]
    }
  }
  statement {
    sid = "allow_snowflake_subscription"
    principals {
      type        = "AWS"
      identifiers = [snowflake_storage_integration.integration.storage_aws_iam_user_arn]
    }

    actions   = ["SNS:Subscribe"]
    resources = [aws_sns_topic.my_sns_topic.arn]
  }

# Error starts in this block I believe
# The json file looks like in the tutorial shown.
  statement {
    sid = "allow_error_integration"

    principals {
      type        = "AWS"
      identifiers = [snowflake_notification_integration.error_integration.aws_sns_iam_user_arn]
    }
    actions = ["sts:AssumeRole"]
    condition {
      test     = "StringEquals"
      variable = "sts:ExternalId"
      values   = [snowflake_notification_integration.error_integration.aws_sns_external_id]
    }
    resources = [aws_sns_topic.my_sns_topic.arn]
  }
}

# ERROR HERE
resource "aws_sns_topic_policy" "snowflake_s3_pipe_notification_error" {
  arn    = aws_sns_topic.my_sns_topic.arn
  policy = data.aws_iam_policy_document.snowflake_notification_error.json
}
```

The error is:

> Error: InvalidParameter: Invalid parameter: Policy statement action out of service scope!status code: 400, request id: 5c75a285-294b-56b7-ad4d-f915d5e0b01b

> with module.datalake_dev["my-snowpipe"].module.s3_integration.aws_sns_topic_policy.snowflake_notification_error, on ../snowflake/s3_integration/s3_integration/error_integration.tf line 79, in resource "aws_sns_topic_policy" "snowflake_notification_error":
> 79: resource "aws_sns_topic_policy" "snowflake_notification_error" {

Comment: You mean this instructions: "Modify the Trust Relationship in the IAM Role"?

Answer (score 1):

The action `"SNS:Receive"` is not allowed to be in the policy statement. All of the allowed actions are listed in the AWS documentation at https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sns/latest/dg/sns-access-policy-language-api-permissions-reference.html#sns-valid-policy-actions

Comment: There's also https://docs.aws.amazon.com/service-authorization/latest/reference/list_amazonsns.html which lists what can be added to an Action part of a policy document.